# How do you read a csv file into a two dimensional array in BASH?

Tags: arrays, bash, csv, shell

How do you read a csv file into a two dimensional array in BASH?  The script needs to be dynamic enough where it can take csv files with variable number of rows and columns.

For example, if I have a csv file that looks like

```
AVERAGE     STDEV     MAX
17          18        19
```

or

```
AVERAGE     STDEV     MAX     MIN
17          18        19      1
```

Comment: This sounds like a bit much for bash (which doesn't even directly support two dimensional arrays).  Why not use Perl or Python?

Comment: It may be possible to use two one dimensional arrays.  Reading from a file to pack the arrays is covered in this link.  Not exactly what you are asking for, but it may help you to look at the problem differently.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173774/how-to-read-columns-from-csv-file-into-array-in-bash/62784951#62784951)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to simulate a two-dimensional array is to keep the rows as strings in a one-dimensional array and unpack them at each iteration. You will have to choose a suitable delimiter that doesn't appear in the data. Since you mention CSV, I'll use a comma, but this won't be smart enough to handle data like this with embedded commas:

```
name, start date, visits, games, balance
"Williamson, Dennis", "January 11, 2007", 12, 42, 17000
```

Here's a simple example of iterating over the values in a simulated two-dimensional array:

```
# avg, stddev, max, min
data_array=(
            "17,18,19,1"
            "12,14,16,2"
            "6,8,10,3"
            )

saveIFS=$IFS

for row in ${data_array[@]}
do
    IFS=","
    cols=($row)
    IFS=$saveIFS
    for col in ${cols[@]}
    do
        newval=$(do_something $col)
    done
done
```

Making changes to the contents of the array is possible:

```
rowidx=2
colidx=2
IFS=","
cols=(${data_array[rowidx]})
cols[colidx]=$some_value
data_array[rowidx]="${cols[*]}"
IFS=$saveIFS
```

As you can see, it gets complicated fast and there are lots of gotchas which I haven't mentioned. Use Python.

Answer (score 0):

bash supports only one-dimensional arrays.  To see an emulation of 2 dimensions check out 
twodim.sh in the advanced bash scripting guide:

example 27.17 in

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

And I agree this does sound like homework.